# REGEXP_REPLACE URL BIGQUERY

Tags: sql, regex, google-bigquery, regexp-replace

I have two types of URL's which I would need to clean, they look like this:

`["//xxx.com/se/something?SE_{ifmobile:MB}{ifnotmobile:DT}_A_B_C_D_E_F_G_H"]` 
`["//www.xxx.com/se/car?p_color_car=White?SE_{ifmobile:MB}{ifnotmobile:DT}_A_B_C_D_E_F_G_H"]`

The outcome I want is;
`SE_{ifmobile:MB}{ifnotmobile:DT}_A_B_C_D_E_F_G_H"`

I want to remove the brackets and everything up to SE, the URLS differ so I want to remove:

First URL 
`["//xxx.com/se/something?`

Second URL: 
`["//www.xxx.com/se/car?p_color_car=White?`

I can't get my head around it,I've tried this `.*\/` . 
 But it will still keep strings I don't want such as:

(1 url) =
`something?` 

(2 url) `car?p_color_car=White?`

Comment: Looks like `.*\?` will do.

Comment: When I try regexp_replace(FinalUrls, r'.*\?') FinalUrl, I get error "No matching signature for function REGEXP_REPLACE for argument types: STRING, STRING.)

Comment: Sure, you forgot the replacement, `''`. See [reference](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#regexp_replace).

Comment: Ah, Got it. Worked with regexp_replace(FinalUrls, r'.*\?',"") FinalUrl,, however the last bracket is still there. Any hint on how I can remove that one? SE_{ifmobile:MB}{ifnotmobile:DT}_A_B_C_D_E_F_G_H"]

Comment: Then use `.*\?|\]$`

Comment: Thanks I fixed it eventually with `regexp_replace(FinalUrls, r'.*\?|\]|\"',"") FinalUrl,`

Comment: Ah, you need `'.*\?|"\]$'` then. `"` is not any special regex metacharacter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
regexp_replace(FinalUrls, r'.*\?|"\]$', '')
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fXVLpO/1)

**Details**

- `.*\?` - any zero or more chars other than line breakchars,  as many as possible and then `?` char
- `|` - or
- `"\]$` - a `"]` substring at the end of the string.

Mind the `regexp_replace` syntax, you can't omit the replacement argument, see [reference](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#regexp_replace):

> `REGEXP_REPLACE(value, regexp, replacement)`
>
> Returns a `STRING` where all substrings of `value` that match regular
> expression `regexp` are replaced with `replacement`.
>
> You can use backslashed-escaped digits (\1 to \9) within the
> `replacement` argument to insert text matching the corresponding
> parenthesized group in the `regexp` pattern. Use \0 to refer to the
> entire matching text.

Comment: I had another question for an additional problem I'm facing with the URL. I have two URLS which can either have a "?" or "&". And I would need to have an "OR" condition in the following. I tried with 'regexp_replace(Url, r'.*\&|\?|"\]$',"")' But it doesn't effect when there's a "?". Ex. of URL                                                                                        ["//xxx.com/se/something?SE_{ifmobile:MB}{ifnotmobile:DT}_A_B_C_D_E_F_G_H"]            
["//xxx.com/se/something&SE_{ifmobile:MB}{ifnotmobile:DT}_A_B_C_D_E_F_G_H"]

Comment: @user3052850 Try `.*[?&]|"\]$`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/fXVLpO/2).